# Парралельная операция ввода вывода в WebClient, помогите разобраться

Tags: .net, файлы, c++-cli, android-asynctask, webclient

Нет сил уже, я в тупике. Скорее всего не вижу то что в глаза бросается. ОЧЕНЬ ПРОШУ: Гляньте плз... Кода слегка многовато поэтому чутка опишу словами чтоб было понятно куда смотреть то в первую очередь, предлагаю сперва не смотреть код чтоб понять в целом...

Смысл кода: Копирование папок с файлами на основе WebClient для осуществления асинхронности операций. Пользователь выбирает пункт в лист боксе, затем ему идет вопрос "сделать ли бекап?" (меня интересует именно эта ветка условий) после чего идет вот эта функция подписывающая клиент на события и кидающая ее в следующий этап (все списки файлов были созданы заранее):

```
void CopyBackup(){
    copier = gcnew WebClient();
    copier->DownloadProgressChanged += gcnew System::Net::DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(this, &CopyFrm::OnCopyProgressChanged);
    copier->DownloadFileCompleted += gcnew System::ComponentModel::AsyncCompletedEventHandler(this, &CopyFrm::OnCopyFileCompleted);
    StartCopy();
}
```

Следующий этап является повторяемым после копирования (а по факту скачивания) каждого файла (см. в самый низ на обработчик OnCopyFileCompleted), но когда все файлы забекаплены (перекидывает на следующую функцию):

```
void StartCopy(){
    if (InputFiles->Count > 0){
        String^ InputFile = Convert::ToString(InputFiles->Dequeue());
        String^ OutputFile = Convert::ToString(OutputFiles->Dequeue());
        copier->DownloadFileAsync(gcnew Uri(InputFile), OutputFile);
    }
    if (InputFiles->Count <= 0)
        CopyNew();
}
```

Ну собственно бекап готов в новой папке и можно приступать копировать новые файлы на место работы заменяя старые. Далее все тоже самое что и в CopyBackup(), только в CopyNew() дополнительно подготавливаются списки файлов и делается новая подписка для Wbclient^ copier, там есть пару элементов отслеживания багов, к делу не относится, списки файлов составляются без проблем и всегда верно, на данном этапе никаких проблем нет:

```
void CopyNew(){
    lbl_CopyFrm_status->Text = "Copying new files...";
    FilesCopied = 0;
    copier->DownloadFileCompleted -= gcnew System::ComponentModel::AsyncCompletedEventHandler(this, &CopyFrm::OnCopyFileCompleted);
    copier->DownloadFileCompleted += gcnew System::ComponentModel::AsyncCompletedEventHandler(this, &CopyFrm::OnCopyFileCompleted2);
    array<String^>^ FilesToCopy = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles(Path::Combine(pc->OBMFolder(), modName), "*.*", IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
    array<String^>^ FilesInGame = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles(Path::Combine(getGP->ModsFolder(), "SP2", "data"), "*.*", IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
    bool IsOutputFile = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < FilesToCopy->Length; i++){
        InputFiles2->Enqueue(FilesToCopy[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < FilesInGame->Length; j++){
            String^ FileInGame = Path::GetFileName(FilesInGame[j]);
            String^ FileToCopy = Path::GetFileName(FilesToCopy[i]);

            if (FileToCopy == FileInGame){
                String^ resultPath = FilesToCopy[i]->Substring(FilesToCopy[i]->LastIndexOf(modName + "\\"));
                resultPath = resultPath->Replace(modName + "\\", "");
                //MessageBox::Show(resultPath);
                String^ NewPath = Path::Combine(getGP->ModsFolder(), "SP2", "data", GetCommonPathFromEnd(FilesToCopy[i], "C:\\" + resultPath));
                //MessageBox::Show("Input: " + FilesToCopy[i] + Environment::NewLine + "Output: " + NewPath);
                OutputFiles2->Enqueue(NewPath);
            }
        }
    }
    if (InputFiles2->Count != OutputFiles2->Count) MessageBox::Show("InputFiles2: " + InputFiles2->Count + Environment::NewLine + "OutputFiles2: " + OutputFiles2->Count);
    StartCopyNew();
}
```

Далее тоже самое что и StartCopy() но пару ньюансов, поэтому не стал делать универсальной вышеуказанную функцию и тут исключение о паралельности операций WebClient НО ТОЛЬКО В ПЕРВЫЙ ВЫЗОВ ЭТОЙ ФУНКЦИИ. Другими словами, успешных вызовов copier->DownloadFileAsync (без исключений) в StartCopy() повторяется 193 раза, сколько же файлов в папке, а вот в StartCopyNew() при первом вызове copier->DownloadFileAsync вылетает исключение и далее без проблем повторяется 192 успешных раза.

```
void StartCopyNew(){
    //MessageBox::Show("InputFiles2: " + InputFiles2->Count + Environment::NewLine + "OutputFiles2: " + OutputFiles2->Count);
    if (InputFiles2->Count > 0){
        String^ InputFile2 = Convert::ToString(InputFiles2->Dequeue());
        String^ OutputFile2 = Convert::ToString(OutputFiles2->Dequeue());
        lbl_CopyFrm_status->Text = GetCommonPathFromEnd(InputFile2, OutputFile2);
        try {
            copier->DownloadFileAsync(gcnew Uri(InputFile2), OutputFile2);
        }
        catch (Exception^ e) {
            wnd->message(e->ToString(), "1b");
        }
    }
    if (InputFiles2->Count <= 0) {
        XmlDocument^ xml_dox = gcnew XmlDocument;
        xml_dox->Load(pc->MBdat());
        if (xml_dox->SelectSingleNode("//OBM") == nullptr){
            xml->AddNode(pc->MBdat(), "OBM", "options");
            xml->ChangeValue(pc->MBdat(), "options", "OBM", modName);
        }
        wnd->message("Files backed up: " + FilesBackedUp + Environment::NewLine + "New files copied: " + FilesCopied, "1b");
        this->Close();
    }
}
```

ну и в конце прилагаю обработчики событий WebClient^ copier:

```
void OnCopyProgressChanged(System::Object ^sender, System::Net::DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs ^e)
{
    pb_ModStatus->Value = e->ProgressPercentage;
}
void OnCopyFileCompleted(System::Object ^sender, System::ComponentModel::AsyncCompletedEventArgs ^e)
{
    FilesBackedUp++;
    //array<String^>^ FilesToCopy = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles(Path::Combine(pc->OBMFolder(), modName), "*.*", IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
    //pb_OverallStatus->Value = InputFiles->Count * 100 / FilesToCopy->Length;
    StartCopy();
}
void OnCopyFileCompleted2(System::Object ^sender, System::ComponentModel::AsyncCompletedEventArgs ^e)
{
    FilesCopied++;
    //array<String^>^ FilesToCopy = System::IO::Directory::GetFiles(Path::Combine(pc->OBMFolder(), modName), "*.*", IO::SearchOption::AllDirectories);
    //pb_OverallStatus->Value = InputFiles->Count * 100 / FilesToCopy->Length;
    StartCopyNew();
}
```

Да знаю что код можно написать короче, но это будет запутанней для вас, для этого вопроса я 2 часа разбивал универсальный код на более простой для понимания незаинтересованных лиц.

Comment: Какое именно исключение вылетает? Вообще, `WebClient` нельзя использовать для параллельных вызовов. Нужно создавать новый экземпляр для всех одновременных вызовов. Или использовать `HttpClient`. Кроме того, нужно освобождать неуправляемые ресурсы: обязательно вызывайте `Dispose`.

Comment: Не понимаю к чему вы это, но спасибо если прочитали код. Я о том что мой WebClient по идее нигде не вызывается паралельно, каждый новый вызов идет через обработчик DownloadComplete. Укажите пожалуйста строку где я не прав в своих суждениях

Comment: @Smirnov: Ну, у вас могут быть две одновременные загрузки через один и тот же WebClient?

Comment: Судя по всему, да. А это как раз и нельзя.

Comment: хоть убей не вижу где и как

Comment: Предположение основано на заголовке вопроса: _Параллельная операция..._ И увидим мы наконец исключение?

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: WebClient не поддерживает параллельные операции ввода-вывода.
   в System.Net.WebClient.ClearWebClientState()
   в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(Uri address, String fileName, Object userToken)
   в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(Uri address, String fileName)
   в MagicBox2017.CopyFrm.StartCopyNew() в c:\users\lenovo\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\magic box 2017\magic box 2017\copyfrm.h:строка 225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

паралельная операция похоже возникает когда в обрабатывается последний файл в очереди.

```
void StartCopy(){
    if (InputFiles->Count > 0){
        // Забираем имя последнего файла из InputFiles. Count становится раным нулю
        String^ InputFile = Convert::ToString(InputFiles->Dequeue());
        String^ OutputFile = Convert::ToString(OutputFiles->Dequeue());
        // Начинаем закачку, метод вернет управления не дожидаясь конца загрузки
        copier->DownloadFileAsync(gcnew Uri(InputFile), OutputFile);
    }
    // Условие стало истнинным. Начинаем новую закачку не дождавись завершения предыдущей
    if (InputFiles->Count <= 0)
        CopyNew();
}
```

усправляется просто

```
void StartCopy(){
    if (InputFiles->Count > 0){
        String^ InputFile = Convert::ToString(InputFiles->Dequeue());
        String^ OutputFile = Convert::ToString(OutputFiles->Dequeue());
        copier->DownloadFileAsync(gcnew Uri(InputFile), OutputFile);
    } else {
        CopyNew();
    }
}
```

Аналогично исправляем StartCopyNew